# How to put strap on acoustic electric?

Tags: guitar

How does one put a strap on an acoustic electric guitar?  Is there a special strap to buy just for acoustic electrics?

The reason I ask is that the lower strap button also serves as the jack for the guitar cable.  It has a wide diameter, and I find it to be too wide for my guitar strap.  Just getting it on there is an intense struggle.  And then, once on, it doesn’t want to stay, because to me, it seems like the strap was not designed for a button this wide.  And so I bought little rubber disk-shaped strap locks, and those won’t even go on at all because this jack/button is too wide and the rubber won’t stretch that far, not to mention that the design of this jack/button does not provide enough room for both the strap AND the strap lock.

Based on all the troubles I have had, I have lately begun assuming that this guitar is designed for some other special strap.

I’m not sure if my model matters but if so it is a Martin 000cxe.

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 5):

Some minor surgery with an exacto knife, utility knife or a pair of very sharp scissors should do the trick. See my illustration below. First elongate the slot a bit (blue line). If the diameter of the post is bigger than the hole and it still doesn’t sit right then cut the circle out a little more (red line) One might do the trick but both will definitely work. Be very careful not to cut yourself and not to cut too much off the strap.

[image]

Comment: Lately I've been buying belts - 3" wide - from charity shops, etc. At £1 a piece, they're good value, and with a craft knife and a bit of care, they make great guitar straps. Most non-adjustable in the end, but since it's me wearing them, who cares? This solution seems so obvious! Only downside is, can't use straploks with those buttons/sockets.+1.

Comment: @Tim That’s a great idea if they’re long enough, especially since a decent leather strap costs $30-$100. I have bought large sheets of leather and made my own straps. I can customize the width and length I want. The hard part is getting nice clean straight cuts the length of the strap.

Comment: 5'4" and wearing guitar/bass high means most will fit! Only problem is if the leather's too thick, it won't take Dunlop straploks easily - or at all. But now, I can have a dedicated strap (whatever colour) for each, rater than having to remember to swap one strap over for gigs. Carrying gaffer tape has got me out of that trouble before. Doubled, it's plenty strong enough, if a tad uncomfortable. A good sharp craft knife, or scalpel, along a metal straightedge the whole length ought to do the cutting well.

Comment: I'd suggest getting a suitable sized leather punch (available from the usual online suppliers) - that's what I use to adjust holes in straps to accomodate strap locks. Much easier to get it right and tidy than using a knife. See (e.g.) https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pieces-Hollow-Leather-Punch-Heavy/dp/B07L1G5J8V

Comment: @MarkBluemel Yes a hole punch will give you a cleaner hole for sure if you have or want to buy a set. Without having one large enough for a strap  I’ve done ok with a little care and patience. It doesn’t look super pretty but it’s covered by the wide part of the strap button.

Answer (score 0):

John's idea is the best, but, if you need to use a locking end, you'll have to drill another hole somewhere near the original strap button, for the locking button. Or, better, maybe, depending on skill level, put the locking button where the jack socket is, and replace that in another position with another jack socket in a convenient place, further round the curve of the body.